# How do i write two almost identical javascript functions into one, based on addEventListener ass triggers

Tags: javascript, file, function

I have spent most of today wrapping my head around this. I have two ways of triggering the same event.
1. by clicking an input:file selector, or
2. by drag'n'dropping a file into a "dropzone"

the only difference between the events is that the file API uses different approaches. 
and it seems that the only arguments allowed inside the eventListeners function call is (event). I might have missed something, but any help is much appreciated

but it really is annoying to just copy paste almost identical code. is there a way to write these two functions "fileSelect(event) and dropSelect(event)" into one?

the code:

```
function fileSelect(event){

    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    selectedFile = event.target.files[0];       //Uses ".files" from the file API in HTML5. In this case accessing info on a single file (files[0]).

    //Insert file info
    document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = "filename: " + selectedFile.name;
    document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = "filetype: " + selectedFile.type;
    document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = "filesize: " + parseFloat(selectedFile.size/1024).toFixed(1) + " kb";
}

//parse the info from a drag'n'drop-selected image. WRITE THESE 2 FUNCTIONS INTO ONE!
function dropSelect(event){

    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    selectedFile = event.dataTransfer.files[0];     //Uses ".files" from the file API in HTML5. In this case accessing info on a single file (files[0]).

    //Insert file info
    document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = "filename: " + selectedFile.name;
    document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = "filetype: " + selectedFile.type;
    document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = "filesize: " + parseFloat(selectedFile.size/1024).toFixed(1) + " kb";
}




//add onchange event to the file_select input:file. This will run function "fileSelect", onChange. 
document.getElementById('file_select').addEventListener('change', fileSelect, false);

//start fileselect when drag'n'drop.
function handleDragOver(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

document.getElementById('upload_box').addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
document.getElementById('upload_box').addEventListener('drop', dropSelect, false);
```

Comment: It's the same method: refactor out the part that's different and pass it in to the refactored function--it's a single argument that gets the `selectedFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function select(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    selectedFile = (event.dataTransfer || event.target).files[0];

    //Insert file info
    document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = "filename: " + selectedFile.name;
    document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = "filetype: " + selectedFile.type;
    document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = "filesize: " + parseFloat(selectedFile.size/1024).toFixed(1) + " kb";
}
```

Comment: It returns the first part which evaluates as `true`

Comment: @Piyuesh I have to correct my comment or rather be more precisely (I should not write these things at the end of the day...^^). The statement returns the left parameter if this is a truthy value otherwise the right parameter - regardless of its value (truthy or falsy)

Answer (score 0):

Factor out common code:

```
function insertFileInfo(file) {
    //Insert file info
    document.getElementById('filename').innerHTML = "filename: " + file.name;
    document.getElementById('filetype').innerHTML = "filetype: " + file.type;
    document.getElementById('filesize').innerHTML = "filesize: " + parseFloat(file.size/1024).toFixed(1) + " kb";
}

function fileSelect(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    insertFileInfo(event.target.files[0]);
}

function dropSelect(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    insertFileInfo(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work
change in @andreas code 
    selectedFile = (event.dataTransfer || event.target).files[0];

to

```
selectedFile = (event.dataTransfer ? event.dataTransfer.files[0] : event.target.files[0]);
```